# make dynamic graph with PyQt5 and Matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I want to read data and plot dynamic graph, so I learn matplotlib with PyQt5. I find example but it's for PyQt4 [there](http://hyry.dip.jp/tech/code/code.html/16). I modify it to PyQt5 but it had some problem, when I click start button it says error

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py",
>   line 1305, in _on_timer ret = func(*args, **kwargs) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 1049, in _step still_going = Animation._step(self, *args) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 855, in _step self._draw_next_frame(framedata, self._blit) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 873, in _draw_next_frame self._pre_draw(framedata, blit) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 886, in _pre_draw self._blit_clear(self._drawn_artists,
>   self._blit_cache) File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py",
>   line 926, in _blit_clear a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
>   KeyError: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1067718d0

This is my code, could someone help me??

```
import sys, os, random
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Ultimately, this is a QWidget (as well as a FigureCanvasAgg, etc.)."""
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        # We want the axes cleared every time plot() is called
        self.axes.hold(False)

        self.compute_initial_figure()

        #
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        pass

class AnimationWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.canvas = MyMplCanvas(self, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.start_button = QPushButton("start", self)
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("stop", self)
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.on_start)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.on_stop)
        hbox.addWidget(self.start_button)
        hbox.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.x = np.linspace(0, 5*np.pi, 400)
        self.p = 0.0
        self.y = np.sin(self.x + self.p)
        self.line, = self.canvas.axes.plot(self.x, self.y, animated=True, lw=2)




    def update_line(self, i):
        self.p += 0.1
        y = np.sin(self.x + self.p)
        self.line.set_ydata(y)
        return [self.line]

    def on_start(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.canvas.figure, self.update_line,
                                 blit=True, interval=25)

    def on_stop(self):
        self.ani._stop()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    aw = AnimationWidget()
    aw.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your code and it seems that the only real problem happens when you click start twice without stopping the animation.

One way to solve this (without going into the details of animated plots), is to prevent the start and stop buttons from doing anything when they aren't supposed to.

The way to do this is to add an attribute to the `AnimationWidget` class that records whether the animation is playing. So put this somewhere in the `__init__` method of `AnimationWidget`:

```
self.playing = False
```

Then, change the `on_start` and `on_stop` methods to

```
def on_start(self):
    if self.playing:
        pass
    else:
        self.playing = True
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.canvas.figure,
            self.update_line,
            blit=True, interval=25
        )
```

and

```
def on_stop(self):
    if self.playing:
        self.playing = False
        self.ani._stop()
    else:
        pass
```

This makes it so the animation won't start twice and give errors and graphical glitches.